# Why is my wx.App interfering with my matplotlib plots?

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython

I am trying to build a GUI with wxPython to control a pretty stable, well-established model.  The standard output of the model includes a series of plots to screen done via matplotlib.  These plots are all OK if the model is run from the command line.  If I run from my new GUI, however, they all show up, but I have no control over them:  I can't click their respective "save" buttons;  if they get covered up by other windows, they are "grayed out" when the blocking window is moved away.  Things like that.  If I close my GUI window, however, I get full control of my plots again.  But this is no way to run this code.

I think my procedure is pretty standard.  The bare outlines of the code are:

```
import wx
import model_code

class gui_for_model(wx.Frame):
    # lots of stuff with hooks into model_code,
    # including a "go" button that starts model_code running

#end of class

app=wx.App(False)
gm = gui_for_model()
app.MainLoop()
```

Anyone know what I should do differently?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't know much about matplotlib, but if it has its own GUI code, you may not be able to run its event loop at the same time as wxPython's. You might be forced to run matplotlib in a background thread.

Comment: Thanks to everyone.  You had it right.  @Yoriz: Changing the backend did the trick.  Thanks.  Put that in as an answer and I'll be glad to hit the accept button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a link to a site that has some demo code of using matplotlib with wxPython GUIs.
[eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2008/08/01/matplotlib-with-wxpython-guis)

Also this - [matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html](http://matplotlib.org/faq/usage_faq.html) talks about changing the backend.

And i found a package on pypi [pypi.python.org/pypi/wxmplot/0.9.12](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/wxmplot/0.9.12)